# Subgroups of special linear group $SL_n(F)$ over a finite field F

Tags: matrices, group-theory

Let $F$ be a field with $|F| = q = p^m$ and $G = SL_n(F).$

We know that the center $Z(SL_n(F))$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and is of order at most n.

Also since $|SL_n(F)| = \frac{\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(q^n-q^i)}{q-1},$ we have Sylow p-subgroups, where $p$ is some prime dividing $q-1.$

Do we know, in general, what are the normal subgroups or the subgroups of $SL_n(F)?$

Comment: Every finite group is a subgroup of some $SL_n(F)$.

Comment: On the other hand, if $n\geq 3$, or $n=2$ and $|F|\geq 4$, then the only proper normal subgroups of $SL_n(F)$ are subgroups of the centre.

Comment: Thanks @DavidA.Craven. Can we say something about the subgroups of G?

Comment: Yes. Every finite group is a subgroup of some $SL_n(F)$. Other than that, not really.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot